# Values From Two TextFields Are Getting Added To The First

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

Hope somebody can help me with this problem I am having in Swift. I have three text fields where the price, then the percent interest, and lastly the number of months are supposed to be entered. However when I enter the percent or the number of months, they get added to the price when I run my simulator. Any help figuring out this would be greatly appreciated, since I have been struggling.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var priceTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var payoutTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var leasingPeriodTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var payoutLabel: UILabel!

    var amt: Int = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        priceTextField.delegate = self
        payoutTextField.delegate = self
        leasingPeriodTextField.delegate = self

        priceTextField.placeholder = updateAmount()
    }

    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        if let digit = Int(string) {
            amt = amt * 10 + digit

            if amt > 1_000_000_00 {
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Indtast venligst 1 million eller mindre", message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))

                present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

                priceTextField.text = ""

                amt = 0
            } else {
                priceTextField.text = updateAmount()
            }
        }

        if string == "" {
            amt = amt/10

            priceTextField.text = updateAmount()
        }

        return false
    }

    func updateAmount() -> String? {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()

        formatter.numberStyle = NumberFormatter.Style.currency
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "da_DK")

        let amount = Double(amt/100) + Double(amt%100)/100

        return formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: amount))
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: 
        UIEvent?) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        if textField == priceTextField {
            payoutTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
        } else if textField == payoutTextField {
            leasingPeriodTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
        } else if textField == leasingPeriodTextField{
            leasingPeriodTextField.resignFirstResponder()
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't hardcode `priceTextField` in `shouldChangeCharactersIn`. Use the `textField` parameter. Keep in mind that `shouldChangeCharactersIn` (and any other text field delegate methods you might have) will be called for all three text fields. If you want different processing for each text field, you need to add some `if` statements.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if textField === priceTextField {
        // logic just for the price field
    } else {
        // The other text fields
        // return true
    }
}
```

This is just an example of what you might want depending on your needs.

But remember to use the `textField` parameter in the logic instead of hardcoding a specific outlet (other than seeing which text field is being processed).

Comment: I prefer using a switch `switch textField { case priceTextField:  // logic just for the price field default: // The other text fields`

Comment: @LeoDabus Will a `switch` perform an `===` or just an `==`?

Comment: what is issue with `==` i know that `===` compare references

Comment: @AbdelahadDarwish In a situation like this the goal is to compare two reference types to see if they reference the same instance so `===` is more correct (and more efficient). `==` sees if the two objects represent the same "data". We are not concerned with that equality in this situation.

Comment: what mean by same data  Are it compare text if we use `== `, or  ==  in this case mean `is`  so `textfield is priceTextField `

Comment: @AbdelahadDarwish Whatever the `==` function (or `isEqual:` in the case of `UIView`) compares to see if two objects represents the same data.

Comment: @Paulw11 I just discovered a typo in my little `switch` test. Turns out the `isEqual:` is being called. So Swift `switch` uses `==`, not `===`. This makes it consistent. `switch` uses `==` for both reference and value types.

Answer (score 0):

Because you update  `priceTextField` at `shouldChangeCharactersIn`  without check if current active textfield is  `priceTextField`

```
 func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

            if  textField === priceTextField {
 if let digit = Int(string) {
            amt = amt * 10 + digit

            if amt > 1_000_000_00 {
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Indtast venligst 1 million eller mindre", message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))

                present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

                priceTextField.text = ""

                amt = 0
            } else {
                priceTextField.text = updateAmount()
            }
           }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are adding the same viewController class as delegate for all the three textfield

> textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String)

is getting called whenever text in anyone of the text fields is changed. In order to avoid that you can do the same check as you are doing in textFieldShouldReturn.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting all textfields delegate to the UITextFieldDelegate and hence the method textField(_:shouldChangeCharactersIn:replacementString:) gets called on every textfield

You have amt as variable that get updated based on

```
 if let digit = Int(string) { 
    amt = amt * 10 + digit
    //if interest or month this well be skipped 
     if amt > 1_000_000_00 {
     }
    // you get here .. while amt is already updated so your price will update as well
     else {
      priceTextField.text = updateAmount() 
    }
    ....
    }
```

you can do this (let temp = amt * 10 + digit) **but check if the textfield is the price first**

```
 if let digit = Int(string) { 
        let temp = amt * 10 + digit
         if temp > 1_000_000_00 {
            //update amt = 0
         }
         else {
          priceTextField.text = updateAmount() 
        }
        ....
        }
```